# how to retrieve image from database in laravel 5.1?

Tags: image, laravel, get

I have image name in the database and image upload in `public/image` folder.

Now I want to show the image on the web page.

How do I do this?

I am using

```
<img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $item->Photo }}" alt="{{ $item->Title }}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [asset()](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset) helper function, like so:

```
<img src="{{ asset("images/$item->Photo") }}" alt="{{ $item->Title }}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<img src="{{ asset('/image') }}" />`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to add a method to your user model.

That method will return the url of your image, you will name that method getImageUrl() for example.

your function :

```
public function getImageUrl(){
    return asset($this->image);
}
```

That way you just have to do something like this in your view

```
<img src="{{ $user->getImageUrl() }}" />
```

Then if at some point you change the storage location of your pictures you just have to change it in the getImageUrl function.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{HTML::image("images/$item->YourDBFieldNameOfImageURL", "ALT description", "");}}
```

Comment: Its worth mentioning that to use this method as of 5.1 you need to install the package from the Laravel Collective see https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html